# Extending Internal Link and External Link to allow selection of Images

Tags: c#, image, hyperlink, sitecore, sitecore7

I need to extend selection of external and Internal Link and provide a image selection.

Please see the snapshot in the below :
[image]

Here the above snapshot allows you to add properties for External Link.In the same popup can we add a field Called Image(as shown in screenshot) which will allow user to select images from the media library??

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sitecore 7.2 and want to update internal link then you need to do with Sitecore speak and in case of external link simply update under /shell/Applications/Dialogs/ExternalLink folder.

To render this field create CustomLinkRenderer class and inheri this class by LinkRenderer of Sitecore.Kernel.dll.

```
Please see below code for CustomLinkRenderer

public class CustomLinkRenderer : LinkRenderer
    {
        public CustomLinkRenderer(Item item)
            : base(item)
        {

        }
        public override RenderFieldResult Render()
        {
            string str8;
            SafeDictionary<string> dictionary = new SafeDictionary<string>();
            dictionary.AddRange(this.Parameters);
            if (MainUtil.GetBool(dictionary["endlink"], false))
            {
                return RenderFieldResult.EndLink;
            }
            Set<string> set = Set<string>.Create(new string[] { "field", "select", "text", "haschildren", "before", "after", "enclosingtag", "fieldname" });
            LinkField linkField = this.LinkField;
            if (linkField != null)
            {
                dictionary["title"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { dictionary["title"], linkField.Title });
                dictionary["target"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { dictionary["target"], linkField.Target });
                dictionary["class"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { dictionary["class"], linkField.Class });
            }
            string str = string.Empty;
            string rawParameters = this.RawParameters;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawParameters) && (rawParameters.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '=', '&' }) < 0))
            {
                str = rawParameters;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                Item targetItem = this.TargetItem;
                string str3 = (targetItem != null) ? targetItem.DisplayName : string.Empty;
                string str4 = (linkField != null) ? linkField.Text : string.Empty;
                str = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { str, dictionary["text"], str4, str3 });
            }
            string url = this.GetUrl(linkField);
            if (((str8 = this.LinkType) != null) && (str8 == "javascript"))
            {
                dictionary["href"] = "#";
                dictionary["onclick"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { dictionary["onclick"], url });
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary["href"] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { dictionary["href"], url }));
            }
            // Add onclick attribute for Google event tracking 
            dictionary["onclick"] = LinkField.GetAttribute("on_click");
            StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder("<a", 0x2f);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dictionary)
            {
                string key = pair.Key;
                string str7 = pair.Value;
                if (!set.Contains(key.ToLowerInvariant()))
                {
                    FieldRendererBase.AddAttribute(tag, key, str7);
                }
            }
            tag.Append('>');
            if (!MainUtil.GetBool(dictionary["haschildren"], false))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
                    return RenderFieldResult.Empty;
                }
                tag.Append(str);
            }
            return new RenderFieldResult { FirstPart = tag.ToString(), LastPart = "</a>" };
        }
    }
```

You need to extend this class as per your need to render image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a whole field and not just an external link inside of a rich text field, you should create a custom field based on the documentation to do so in SDN:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx

You can inherit most functionality from the current link field.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually extend any dialog by editing the xml files in /shell/Applications/Dialogs

In another thread I have shown how to add a maxlength to the title field, that should help you get on your way: [Limit number of Characters entered for Link Title Field in General Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420527/sitecore-7limit-number-of-characters-entered-for-link-title-field-in-general-li/23426237)